# ASP.NET Entity Framework - How to use compile query while using single context per request?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, objectcontext

Following is one of my repository class. I am using single context per request. So for each subsequent call to GetSpecificationList() will create a new object context & dispose it when it will be out of scope. Now i am confuse of following points-

**1. For each subsequent call to GetSpecificationList() it will create a new context. So should i use NoTracking option in GetSpecificationList() method. Will it give any benefit?**

**2. Suppose we need to call GetSpecificationList() frequently. Should i used compile query for GetSpecificationList(). AS we are disposing context on each request where EF will be storing compile query information.**

**3. In InsertUpdateProjectSpecification() method, to modify the entity we doing following call just to inform EF which entity we are going to modify. Is there any alternative of this overhead?**

objProjectSpecification= context.ProjectSpecifications.Where(p => 
                p.ProjectSpecificationId == spec.ProjectSpecificationId).FirstOrDefault();

```
public static List<ProjectSpecification>  GetSpecificationList(int projectId)
{
    using (PropDBAdminEntities context = new PropDBAdminEntities())
        {
         return context.ProjectSpecifications.Where(p=>  
                           p.ProjectId==projectId).ToList();
         }
}

public static void InsertUpdateProjectSpecification(List<ProjectSpecification>     
                 projectSpecificationList)
{

     using (PropDBAdminEntities context = new PropDBAdminEntities())
     {
           ProjectSpecification objProjectSpecification=null;
           projectSpecificationList.ForEach(spec =>
           {
               if (spec.ProjectSpecificationId == 0)
                  {
                      spec.CreatedBy = 1;
                      spec.CreatedDate=DateTime.Now;
                       context.ProjectSpecifications.AddObject(spec);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    spec.ModifiedBy = 1;
                    spec.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        objProjectSpecification= context.ProjectSpecifications.Where(p => 
            p.ProjectSpecificationId == spec.ProjectSpecificationId).FirstOrDefault();
                     spec.CreatedBy = objProjectSpecification.CreatedBy;
                    spec.CreatedDate = objProjectSpecification.CreatedDate;
                    context.ProjectSpecifications.ApplyCurrentValues(spec);
                   }
                 });
                    context.SaveChanges();
            }

   }
```

Please suggest.

Thanks,

@Paul

Comment: 2) Depends on which version of the .net RunTime you are using. You should use .net 4.5 for the optimal expected (magical) caching behavior.

Comment: Aron, even we use EF5 where EF will be storing compile query as we are disposing context after each call?

Comment: Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, LINQ queries are cached automatically. However, you can still use compiled LINQ queries to reduce this cost in later executions and compiled queries can be more efficient than LINQ queries that are automatically cached. Note that LINQ to Entities queries that apply the Enumerable.Contains operator to in-memory collections are not automatically cached. Also parameterizing in-memory collections in compiled LINQ queries is not allowed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx